# Visualize predicted results in PowerBI

Tags: python, r, machine-learning, powerbi

I've searched all PowerBI documentation, but still haven't find answer to my question:

Is it possible to import `Python` or `R` scrips to PowerBI, learn ML model and visualize predicted results. But with possability to change one feature value in dropbox and see how the prediction changed?

The most relevant links i found:

- https://community.powerbi.com/t5/Community-Blog/How-To-Get-Predictions-from-Power-BI-Machine-Learning-Model/ba-p/656815
- https://powerbi.microsoft.com/it-it/blog/visualizing-and-interacting-with-your-azure-machine-learning-studio-experiments/
- https://powerbi.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/power-bi-desktop-august-2018-feature-summary/#python

Comment: you can use python and r, but the outcome must be e.g. a table in powerbi

Answer (score 0):

You mean something like [this](https://www.absentdata.com/power-bi/python-machine-learning-in-power-bi/)?

Comment: Not actually. The idea is train model on train set, insert validation set, take one observarion (row) and change one factor, while other factors for this observation are "frozen", and see how prediction changes

Comment: Not sure I fully understand, but given you have an ML model that has weights from training and the model process the results (predicts) based on those weights and some fixed target function then you can have the same result you want by having the data run throw that calculation each time you filter it (meaning, when you -  "take one observation (row) and change one factor")